# I am trying to deploy static react app to heroku, but i get error like "cross-env: not found"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, package.json

Error occurs while deploying. locally everything works fine.

I am aware that cross-env is a development dependency. Heroku, by default, only installs production dependencies.

below is the package.json and error log. Please let me know how to solve it.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "jest": "^27.0.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.39.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}

Error log:

,,,
2021-06-21T14:58:17.290672+00:00 app[web.1]: > project@1.0.0 start /app
2021-06-21T14:58:17.290673+00:00 app[web.1]: > cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve
2021-06-21T14:58:17.290673+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-21T14:58:17.296829+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: cross-env: not found
2021-06-21T14:58:17.316513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-21T14:58:17.317015+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-06-21T14:58:17.317223+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-06-21T14:58:17.317548+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-06-21T14:58:17.324706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! project@1.0.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve`
2021-06-21T14:58:17.324883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-06-21T14:58:17.325099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-06-21T14:58:17.327281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 start script.
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
      mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app.js',
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: isDevelopment ? 'bundle.js' : 
        'bundle.hash.js',
      },
```

Comment: Try delete the node modules and re-install

Comment: @SarunUK: Hi Sarun. Thanks. it does not help to delete node modules and reinstall. my question was what I must change in the package.json for that "cross env" error.  I have added an error log in my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: SOLVED:    incase if anyone looking for an answer, cross-env was not at all needed for me so I removed it. now all good, it deployed to heroku :)